# Programmers should avoid writing to the local file system in cloud?

Tags: file, cloud

Should programmers avoid writing to the local file system  when writing application to be deployed to a cloud? 
Does [this recommendation](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html) apply only to this particular cloud provider (Cloud Foundry)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes, you probably should avoid it.

Most cloud providers - just like Cloud Foundry - recommend that you only keep ephemeral data (like caches) on your local disk, since a single machine may fail or reboot for upgrade or re-balancing at any time and you don't necessarily get the same machine back after a restart.

Many providers provide alternate SAN/SMB mountable disks which you *can* use for persistent data.